# jQuery check for none empty input

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to figure out an issue I am having with jQuery.

I am working in the WordPress backend. I have two divs. The first is an input text that gets populated with an image URL when an 'Upload' button is clicked and an image is selected. The second div is irrelevant but basically, when the first input text div gets populated, I would like the second to show.

Now, I've tried to do simple things like:

```
if ($('#section-logo input').val() != '') {
    logo_position_section.show();
}
```

Which works fine, but only after you click save and the page refreshes.

`focus()` won't work in this case either unless the user manually clicks inside the input text and types something in.

How do I go about checking if there is in fact a value in the first div, but without having to refresh the page and not having to use focus? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind on input change and perform check on load.

```
$(function(){
   var showLogoPosition = function(el) {
        if(el.val() !== '') {
           logo_position_section.show(); 
        }
   },
   input = $('#section-logo input');
   input.change(function(){
       showLogoPosition($(this));
   });

   showLogoPosition(input);
})
```

Comment: Tried something similar earlier - does not work in this case - which left me pretty puzzled.

Comment: It also seems that after you click upload, and the input text field gets populated, the actual value (in the HTML code) does not change... value is blank.

Comment: Well, it should work, provided that `#section-logo input` has some value in it.

Comment: I know it should :p But it's weird that 'value' doesn't actually get populated with anything (when inspecting the element).

Comment: Thanks Yury. Your code looks legit, but it still doesn't work in this case. I did not code this WordPress options framework, so some things leave me puzzled. I should note also, after you select an image and the input gets populated, a new div with a screenshot of the image is added underneath the text field. How could I just check if the div exists, but again, without a page refresh?

Comment: Could you change HTML in the fiddle to what is actually rendered on your page? Is there any actual file field changing or it might be some iframe with form in it to emulate "ajax file transfer"?

Comment: There. So after selecting an image, in the HTML at least, nothing changes (even the value of the input text stays empty (weird)) except the `<div class="screenshot">` gets populated with an image.

Comment: So I guess another solution could be forgetting whether or not the input text is empty (because it's pointless here since it doesn't get updated), and check if a `<img>` exists in `<div class="screenshot">`?

Comment: Same thing. But in both cases, when I select the image, input text gets populated but the other div doesn't show... if I then modify the input text value - say for instance, the image path is `.../wordpress.png` and I change it to `.../wpress.png`, the div shows, so the input change is firing.

Comment: Any time input is populated it should trigger 'change' event. :)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't happen. I have to manually change something in the input text field for it to fire.

Comment: Last idea: bind on click. http://jsfiddle.net/SpKdZ/4/
User gotta click on upload button any way. :)

Comment: Haha ok well that works. Better than nothing! Thanks a lot for your help Yury :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the jQuery change event

```
$('#section-logo input').change( function() {
    if ( $(this).val() !== "" ) {
        logo_position_section.show();
    }
}
```